# .net MAUI: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll'

Tags: .net, dll, maui, maui-windows

I have a problem with MAUI. I can easily run my app in debug mode directly from Visual Studio.
However if I try to run the app installed from my system, the following error occurs.

[image: Missing Dll error]

I tried some tips found on github like install VC Redis but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: I build an MSIX executable using Jenkins with the following command: dotnet publish Application.csproj -c "release" -f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -p:WindowsPackageType=None -p:SelfContained=true -p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true

Comment: Do you mean you have got it worked by building an MSIX executable using Jenkins?

Comment: Sadly yes, but if it is possible to run it in debug it should also be possible to build it using the Visual Studio Installer Tool. And if that is the case, there should also be a command line command that works.

Comment: It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same error today. However not when trying to run the installed app but rather when building the project with the **launchSettings.json** missing. This file was gitignored by default and not uploaded to the repository. So I manually send it over from my old to my new device and the problem was fixed.

Another indicator for the missing file is the **Start Debugging Button** in Visual Studio when targeting Windows:

- When the buttons text is **equal** to your **projects name**, the file is missing.
- When the buttons text is **"Windows Machine"**, the file is present.

---

Sadly I was not able to reproduce your exact case. I removed the launchSettings.json again, published the App, installed the App and was able to run it with no issues.
It would be great to here back from you if you were able to figure that out.